# WebBrowser control get all controls on a thread not working

Tags: c#, winforms, web-control

I have WebBrowser control and i am calling a function to get all the control ID from a thread. the functions works when i called it from the UI thread but does not get any control if called from a separate thread.

I am lost please help

calling:

```
List<WebOparator.WebOparator.WebControls> wcList = oparator.GetAllControlName();
int tryCount = 0;
do
{

if (wcList.Count == 0)
{
    tryCount++;
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    wcList = oparator.GetAllControlName();
 }
 if (tryCount >= 5) break;
 } while (wcList.Count == 0);
```

Method:

```
    public List<WebControls> GetAllControlName()
    {

            List<WebControls> names = new List<WebControls>();
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {

                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (HtmlElement element in myBrowser1.Document.All)
                    {
                        if (element.Id != null)
                        {
                            i++;
                            names.Add(new WebControls() { sl = i, ID = element.Id, TagName = element.TagName });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (HtmlElement element in myBrowser1.Document.All)
                {
                    if (element.Id != null)
                    {
                        i++;
                        names.Add(new WebControls() { sl = i, ID = element.Id, TagName = element.TagName });
                    }
                }
            }
            return names;


    }
```

Edit:

I found that the function goes in loops through all the control and add them to the list but returns an empty list....

Comment: Don't do this.  Use HTML Agility Pack instead.

Comment: There is no point in writing `catch { throw; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeginInvoke()` is asynchronous.
That delegate yuns on the UI thread after the rest of your code finishes.

You want `Invoke()`, which will synchronously wait for the delegate to finish running.